# How to find out if a textfield is a TLF or classic one in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

Is it possible to find out if a textfield is a TLF or classic one in Flash AS3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You can use the `is` keyword to check against class types.

So, if you had a classic text field with an instance name of `classic`, and a TLF text field with an instance name of `tlf`, you could do the following:

```
classic is TLFTextField;  //would be false, because it's classic text
tlf is TLFTextField; //would be true

classic is TextField; //would be true
tlf is TextField; //would be false
```

Comment: Though it's generally a good idea to avoid using TLF text to begin with. You can't even create it in Flash CC anymore.